# Usb flash drive not detected in explorer, device manger and disk management

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

my usb pendrive (sony 16gb) suddenly stopped to work, when inserted its led blink for 1-2 seconds and then nothing happens. In windows (10) it is not detected in explorer, not detected in disk management and not detected in Device Manager. Tried in different computers, under linux environment it is not detected in Gparted. Is there something else I could try before throw it away?

Comment: It sounds like the device experienced a hardware failure, it happens, flash drives do not have an infinite lifespan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB thumbdrives are not eternal, therefore those fail and, since no moving parts are involved, the drive shows no previous sign of malfunction.